# Qt design and performance issue

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qgraphicsitem

I am having some troubles while designing a C++ QT application. Among other things, the application displays the beams (or rays) of some lasers (each laser is composed by around 700 segments starting from the same position and spaced by a constant angle, and a small circle at the other end of the segment materializing the end point). [Here is a drafting of one laser I found on the internet](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC171786.jpg) . Most of the time I have to display 12 lasers (so 12*700 segments), at 30 frames per second. My first implementation works, but it takes a huge amount of CPU (>12%) and the GUI lags a lot.

What I did for the implementation is quite simple: I have a `LaserModel` class, filled by a thread receiving TCP beacons; A `MainWindow` class with a `QGraphicsScene* _scene`; and a `LaserView` class, whose instances are added to the scene. A signal at 30fps triggers the passage of the datas from the model to the view using the `setData()` method.

I did a performance analysis and it seems that 80% of the work of the gui (There is way more than just displaying these lasers) is done by the `drawLine(/*…*/)` methods.

I am sure that there is a more elegant and efficient way to do that.

- First the `setData(/*…*/)` method seems quite ugly to me. I know that I should probably emit a signal (like `laserHasChanged(const LaserModel&))` from the model and catch it in the view (with a slot `onNewData(const LaserModel&)`) but for the performance point of view it seems worse (but it looks better for the coupling point of view, especially because in the future I will probably also display a property tree with the configuration of the lasers(so another view of the same model)).
- More important I am not quite sure about what the `drawLine(const QLine& line)` does, but this part of the code should just “render” the line, not recreate it.

So the question is: how can I drastically improve the performances of the rendering? Especially the drawline part of the paint() method?

Here is the relevant code:

```
class LaserView : public QGraphicsItem {
    /* c-tor, d-tor, members... */
    std::vector<Beam> _beams;
    QRectF _boundingRect;

    void setData(const Sim::Pose& pose, const std::vector<Beam>& beams, const QRectF& boundingRect, const bool& showMaxRanges) {
        /*...*/
        _beams = beams;
        _boundingRect = boundingRect;
    }
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *) {
        painter->setPen(_color);
        // Display only the beams that are stopped by an obstacle
        if (!_showMaxRanges) {
            for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < _beams.size() -1 ; i++) {
                if (!_beams[i].endPointType == laserBeamEndPointType::MAX_RANGE) {
                    _beams[i]._line.setLine(_pose.x, _pose.y, _beams[i]._mapEndPose.x(), _beams[i]._mapEndPose.y());
                    painter->drawLine(_beams[i]._line);
                }
            }
        }
        // Display all beams
        else {
            for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < _beams.size() -1 ; i++) {
                _beams[i]._line.setLine(_pose.x, _pose.y, _beams[i]._mapEndPose.x(), _beams[i]._mapEndPose.y());
                painter->drawLine(_beams[i]._line);
            }
        }
        // Draw a small circle to visualize easily the end points of the beams when they stop against an obstacle
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _beams.size() - 1 ; i++) {
            // Draw the end point in blue if the obstacle is reflective
            if (_beams[i].endPointType == laserBeamEndPointType::REFLECTIVE_OBJECT) {
                painter->setBrush(REFLETIVE_END_POINT_COLOR);
                painter->drawEllipse(_beams[i]._mapEndPose, END_POINT_SIZE, END_POINT_SIZE);                
            }
            // Draw the end point in red if the obstacle is NOT reflective
            else if (_beams[i].endPointType == laserBeamEndPointType::NOT_REFLECTIVE_OBJECT) {
                painter->setBrush(NOT_REFLETIVE_END_POINT_COLOR);
                painter->drawEllipse(_beams[i]._mapEndPose, END_POINT_SIZE, END_POINT_SIZE);                                
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The code seems to be OK. Use profiler to find out what is your performance issue.

Comment: I did. the second `painter->drawLine(_beams[i]._line);` line spend 80% of the application (_showMaxRanges == true)

Comment: You are trying to draw about 250.000 lines per second. No wonder it eats up a bit of CPU. Since your beams are likely to change depending on the obstacle positons, there is not much you can pre-compute. I assume you would have basically the same execution time with or without QT.

Comment: Try to switch from Graphics View to direct drawing on an OpenGL widget.

Comment: @kuroi neko: of course it is a lot to do. But I think that the performance issue has everything to do with QT(or more likely how I use QT), since all the time is spend on the same single `drawLine` method.

Comment: @Pavel Strakhov : I would be happy to use OpenGL and delegate this rendering task to the GPU, but I am not allowed to integrate OpenGL into the build system.

Comment: If your lasers have a fixed position in the scene, maybe you could draw your lines only when the viewpoint changes and then wipe out the occluded parts by computing occlusion shapes based on the ostacles?

Answer (score 2):

You are drawing one line at a time, one ellipse at a time, switching between brushes in the process. There is a significant overhead with these operations (at least with Qt4). You can do better by aggregating these calls to just 3 drawing calls.

you have

```
std::vector<QlineF> lines;
std::vector<QRectF> ellipse_refl_rects;
std::vector<QRectF> ellipse_non_refl_rects;
```

Rather than drawing a line add to `lines` collection. Same for ellipses.
Then at the end you have

```
if(!lines.isempty())
{
    painter->drawLines(&lines[0], lines.size());
}

if(!ellipse_refl_rects.isempty())
{
    painter->setBrush(REFLETIVE_END_POINT_COLOR);
    painter->drawEllipses(&ellipse_refl_rects[0], ellipse_refl_rects.size());
}

if(!ellipse_non_refl_rects.isempty())
{
    painter->setBrush(NOT_REFLETIVE_END_POINT_COLOR);
    painter->drawEllipses(&ellipse_non_refl_rects[0], ellipse_non_refl_rects.size());
}
```

Comment: I completely agree with this; changing pens and brushes will cause a flush in the render engine and grouping items will definitely improve performance on Qt 5 too. One other thing to note for @n3squik, remove all logic from the paint function where possible. This is also why you're seeing the check to _showMaxRanges taking a large percentage of CPU. Create the groups of lines and ellipses before the paint call occurs, possibly in setData( )